# java corrupted double-linked list when use tesseract

Tags: java, crash, jvm, tesseract

I'm using tess4j OCR library to recognize text from images.
Image comes to server -> recognize -> result of operation send in response
When server works with list of images it crashes on the one image with code below.

```
* Error in `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java': corrupted double-linked list: 0x00007f360c00c4f0 *
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7415f)[0x7f36922e815f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x795d6)[0x7f36922ed5d6]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7a6b6)[0x7f36922ee6b6]
/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/jna-3506402/jna9215552986529547192.tmp(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c)[0x7f366ad017a0]
/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/jna-3506402/jna9215552986529547192.tmp(ffi_call+0x20b)[0x7f366ad0129b]
/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/jna-3506402/jna9215552986529547192.tmp(+0x5e41)[0x7f366acf4e41]
/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.33/temp/jna-3506402/jna9215552986529547192.tmp(Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokeVoid+0x22)[0x7f366acf7752]
[0x7f367d200cce]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1200410                            /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:02 1200410                            /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 1200410                            /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/bin/java
020fe000-08285000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

If I try to recognize only problem image I catch TesseractError which is expected.
 When I recognize over 2000 of images on one image I have JVM crash. Images come to server in   separate requests. Any one could help?

Comment: Create a reproducible example and submit an issue on tess4j project page.